# Terminating PyQt App before initUI

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, exit

I am developing a PyQt application that sends mails. It reads the authentication information from a file. I'm trying to check if the authentication is ok before calling `initUI()` and to display an error message and exit the whole app if it doens't.

This is a fragment of my code :

```
class Mailer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('config.ini')

        self.server = config["SMTP SERVER"]
        self.user = config["USER"]
        self.smtpServer = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.server["Host"],self.server["Port"])

        try:
            self.smtpServer.login(self.user["Username"],self.user["Password"])
            self.smtpServer.quit()
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error de autenticación", """El usuario y/o la contraseña en el archivo config.ini son incorrectos.""", QMessageBox.Ok)
            QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

        self.initUI()
```

The problem is that it doesn't exit the application. If I change `QCoreApplication.instance().quit()` by `self.close()` I get the same.

Comment: Surely `self.smtpServer.quit()` should go inside the `except` block?

Comment: That's true, I thought the SMTP Initializator didn't start a connection and it was the `login()` function which did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `sys.exit(0)` ?
(You need `import sys` for this, but you probably imported it already as it is required for pyqt `sys.exit(app.exec_())`)

If it doesn't work, I believe that your problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I don't know if it's the cleanest method but it works!